# Large .img file processing in R (GIS)

Tags: r, gis

I am working with U.S. National Landcover Dataset (NLCD) to classify habitat type at more than 150 sites across the northeast U.S. The dataset is very large (15GB) so I cannot upload it here, but it comes in .img format at 30m resolution. 
 I have GPS coordinates for the center point of all the sites. I would like to be able to extract the proportion of landcover classes in a 1 square kilometer around the point. My questions are:

1)  How do I upload .img files into r?
2)  How do I extract the information from around the GPS coordinates as proportions of the different habitat classes?

Has anyone worked with this dataset in r before? If so I could really use the help. 
Cheers, 
Israel

Comment: The raster package has some ondisk capabilities

Comment: @mnel does this mean that the file wont be stored in ram? But will the raster package be able to process and extract data around my points?

Comment: Yes -- it will read in the data in chunks when required.

Comment: @mnel Thanks! I will start there. Any idea how to extract data from the area surrounding a point in the raster package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to mnel. I have gotten the basic idea to work (code below). Now if anyone could give me a pointer on how to calculate the proportion of each category for every coordinate. The `extract` function gives me matrices of values for each set of coordinates. Is there a way to summarize this data?

```
#load in map and locality data
NLCD<-raster ('NLCD2006/NLCD2006.img')
sites<-read.csv('sites.csv', header=T)
#crop site data to just latitude and longitude
sites<-sites[,4:5]
#convert lat/lon to appropirate projection
str (sites)
coordinates(sites)  <-  c("Longitude",  "Latitude")
proj4string(sites)  <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
sites_transformed<-spTransform(sites, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))

#plot the map
plot (NLCD)
#add the converted x y points
points (sites_transformed, pch=16, col="red", cex=.75)
#extract values to poionts
Landcover<-extract (NLCD, sites_transformed, buffer=1000)
```

Comment: `lapply(Landcover, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `raster` package which can process the files from disk, only reading in chunks at a time.

the `raster` package has an `extract` function with a `buffer` argument. set your buffer to the appropriate value (`1000` if your map units are metres and you want a `km` radius)

Comment: Thanks for the input on the last comment. I am having trouble plotting my sites on the .img map. I assume this is because they must be in different projections. My coordinates are in decimal degrees (WGS 1984) and the img file is in GCS North American 1983. Any suggestions on how to get everything on the same coordinate system so that I can begin to use the exrtact function and the buffer argument.

Comment: @IDelToro `rgdal::spTransform` (on the points, not the raster)