# How read disk image file (.img) in R

Tags: r, import, format, bin

I lack some basis in file formating and maybe some of you can point me in the right direction so I can learn it.

I am using a device that measure the intensity of light resolved in time and saves the data as a .img

Since I am not used to this data file and don't know their usual architecture, how can I extract the data contained inside the file?

The manufacturer manual says:

> *Image files: *.IMG. An ITEX compatible file format is used. The imagestatus is stored in the comment string of an ITEX file (see Appendix Efor details). Either 8, 16 or 32 bit files are generated in non compressedform.*

and then provide me a table on how the data is organized according its bytes.

(Here the link to the appendix of the manual: https://beamline.harima.riken.jp/bl45xu/web_old/Beamline/HiPicFileFormat.pdf)

And here I attach an example of the .img file that I would like to interact with, if some of you want to give it a look (https://gofile.io/d/bEuaZL)

Hereafter I attach an example of the dataframe that I would like to get once I manage to extract the data from the .img

[image: Expected dataframe]

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use the package raster to extract the information of my .img file as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824853/large-img-file-processing-in-r-gis) but unfortunatly the packages is meant for GIS.

By using `readIniFile()`  I get some useful informations on how the images was taken, now I will need to understand how to read the rest of the .img file.
It seems that  `readBin()` comand might be part of the solution but I need to  understand the structure of the data so to get it out correctly.

I will continue to try to see if I manage to unpack that data :)

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Kostr, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you've done a really good job setting up the background of your question. However, in my opinion, you have not really asked a question. What output do you expect from that image you linked? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you, I reformulate my post and I hope it is more clear now. I am looking for a general approach to read the data contained in a .img file.

Comment: The solution came after understanding better the problem. My image was saved in byte of int32 data type. I first understood the structure of the file (header + data) and then extracted what I needed.
In R the solution probably should have come using readBin.